# RealmSwift and watchos2

Tags: swift, realm, watchos-2

Using RealmSwift-0.97.0 and watchos2, I have the following error when trying to run my Watchkit-App for the first time:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
Referenced from: /Users/....

Reason: image not found
```

What could be the mistake ?

I am using the following podfile to incorporate RealmSwift into my project :

```
xcodeproj 'iSquash.xcodeproj'
workspace 'iSquash.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!
link_with 'iSquash', 'iSquash WatchKit Extension'

def shared_pods
      pod 'Realm'
      pod 'RealmSwift'
end

target 'iSquash' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'iSquashTests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'iSquash WatchKit Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '2.0'
    shared_pods
end
```

The same podfile I have used successfully bevore (with Watchos1.2 and an earlier version of RealmSwift...)
Any help appreciated ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

found the solution....

The old Run-Script needed for earlier versions of RealmSwift and watchos1.0 is no longer needed !!!

[image]